# Trying to determine whether an object is a function, and datetime.datetime.now caused a strange problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

Environment:

```
Linux & CPython 3.6.4
```

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to determine if an object is a function. And I do this with the types library, the code I wrote is like the following.

```
class Foo:

    @classmethod
    def is_function(cls, obj):
        ''' determines whether an object is a function
        '''

        return isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType)

    @classmethod
    def is_classmethod(cls, obj):
        ''' determines whether an object is a class method
        '''

        type_ = type(cls.is_classmethod)
        return isinstance(obj, type_)
```

The first function "is_function" dosn't works on class methods. So, I wrote the second function "is_classmethod". And I read the code of the types library in order to find something like "ClassmethodType", but I found the following code, so the type I'm using in the second function is "type(cls.is_classmethod)".

```
# lib/python3.6/types.py at line 11

def _f(): pass
FunctionType = type(_f)
```

Then, I did some experiment with it:

```
class Bar:

    @classmethod
    def b(cls):
        pass

Foo.is_function(Bar.b)     # False
Foo.is_classmethod(Bar.b)  # True
```

These 2 functions work as expected. But, when I pass datetime.datetime.now into these functions, both of them return False.

And I already read the code of datetime library before doing this, datetime.datetime.now is definitely a class method.

```
# lib/python3.6/datetime.py at line 1475

@classmethod
def now(cls, tz=None):
    "Construct a datetime from time.time() and optional time zone info."
    t = _time.time()
    return cls.fromtimestamp(t, tz)
```

I cannot even imagine about this, how could it be? The second function has already been proven, it do detects class methods and I found nothing special on datetime.datetime.now, it just a normal classmethod.

So, what caused this?

Comment: The concept of a "function" or "method" in Python might seem simple, but there are at least 10 different function and method types in the standard implementation, not counting aliases - `types.FunctionType`, `types.MethodType`, `types.BuiltinFunctionType`, `types.WrapperDescriptorType`, `types.MethodWrapperType`, `types.MethodDescriptorType`, `types.ClassMethodDescriptorType`, `staticmethod`, `classmethod`, and `PyInstanceMethod_Type`. (`types.LambdaType` is the same as `types.FunctionType`, and `types.BuiltinMethodType` is the same as `types.BuiltinFunctionType`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't detect `datetime.now` as a classmethod because that method is implemented in C.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now
<built-in method now of type object at 0x7f723093a960>
```

The method definition you found in `datetime.py` is only used as a fallback if the C implementation of the `datetime` module isn't available. On the bottom of `datetime.py`, you'll find this import that attempts to import the C implementation:

```
try:
    from _datetime import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

So the class and method you've found simply aren't used.

Methods implemented in C do not use the `@classmethod` decorator, so your function's `isinstance(...)` check will never succeed. In order to detect a method written in C, you have to make use of the various types defined in the [`types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html) module:

- [`BuiltinMethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.BuiltinMethodType)
- [`WrapperDescriptorType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.WrapperDescriptorType)
- [`MethodDescriptorType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodDescriptorType)
- [`ClassMethodDescriptorType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ClassMethodDescriptorType)
- [`MethodWrapperType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodWrapperType) (for bound dundermethods)

`datetime.now` happens to be an instance of `BuiltinMethodType`:

```
>>> import types
>>> isinstance(datetime.now, types.BuiltinMethodType)
True
```

But if you want to detect all kinds of classmethods, you should check against all of the aforementioned types:

```
def is_classmethod(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, (types.BuiltinMethodType,
                            types.WrapperDescriptorType,
                            types.MethodDescriptorType,
                            types.ClassMethodDescriptorType,
                            types.MethodWrapperType))
```

*However*, you must be aware that there is no difference between *functions* and *methods* if they're defined in C. As such, it is impossible to detect classmethods reliably:

```
>>> is_classmethod(datetime.now)
True
>>> is_classmethod('foo'.__str__)
True
>>> is_classmethod(sorted)
True
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the answer. As you said, I comment these code at the bottom of datetime.py and it fallbacks to that classmethod defined in python.

Comment: "In order to detect a method written in C, you have to use types.BuiltinMethodType" - unless it's a wrapper descriptor, or a method wrapper, or a method descriptor, or one of the other surprisingly large number of C method types. Also, C functions (not methods) also pass that `isinstance` check, because `types.BuiltinMethodType` and `types.BuiltinFunctionType` are the same type.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you're really after a type check. It seems like what you're really looking for is a way to determine whether an object is *callable*, and the way to do that is with the built-in function [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable):

```
>>> callable(datetime.datetime.now)
True
```

Regular function, C function, C method, slot wrapper, NumPy ufunc, whatever, if it can be called, `callable` will return `True`. Checking types is too sensitive to implementation details; Python has too many function and function-like types, and any library can introduce new ones. Also, the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) means that you don't actually get a classmethod object when you try to access a classmethod, so the idea of testing for classmethods is kind of questionable in the first place.

Comment: Actually, I did. These code above is just a fragment, I need to detect a lot of types, not only functions. Callable is not the correct way to detect functions, because classes and objects could also be callable.

Comment: @Mr.I: As far as duck typing goes, those are functions, and they will very often be documented as functions. For example, almost every function in `itertools` is really a class, almost every function in `random` is really a method, most of the core functions in NumPy are really `numpy.ufunc` objects, etc. It is sometimes useful to distinguish them, but prepare for a lot of "what do you mean that's not an X?" moments.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I will pay attention on it :)